# How to read columns with spaces from coldfusion queries?

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfspreadsheet

I am reading data from a spreadsheet. One of the column in the spreadsheet contains spaces.

For Example, Columns names are [first name,last name,roll].

I am getting a `qryObj` after reading the spreadsheet.
Now when i am trying to read first name from the query

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="getName">
    SELECT [first name]
    FROM   qryObj
</cfquery>
```

It is throwing db error. I have tried with `['first name']` also but still it is throwing error.

The error is:

```
Query Of Queries syntax error.
Encountered "[. Incorrect Select List, Incorrect select column
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did crazy stuff like *googling* to see what people had done in other situations, and tried various SQL approaches to escaping non-standard column names (back ticks, square barackets, double quotes, combos thereof) , and drew a blank. So I agree with @da_didi that QoQ/IMQ does not cater for this. You should raise a ticket in the [Adobe bug tracker](http://bugbase.adobe.com/).

You could do `SELECT *`, which removes the need to reference the column name. Or you could serialize the query, use a string replace to rename the column, deserialise it again then QoQ on the revised name. I'd only do this with a small amount of data though.

Or you could push back on the owbner of the XLS file and say "no can do unless you revise your column names".

You could also perhaps suppress the column names as they stand from the XLS file using `excludeHeaderRow`,and then specify your own columns names. How did I find out one could do that? By *RTFMing* the [`<cfspreadsheet>` docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html).

Comment: Serializing to JSON, replacing the column names, then deserializing back to a query worked perfectly for me. Thanks Adam!

Comment: Another, simpler option would be to rename the columns using `qryObj.setColumnNames()` which takes an array of the replacement names. But bear in mind they will be UPPERCASED.

Comment: After 7 years, this has finally been reported as an ACF bug.  https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4211146  (If it was reported earlier, I couldn't find it,)

Comment: @CfSimplicity that method is internal to CF's query class implementation, and Adobe have always stressed they're not supported, and there's no guarantee they will continue to exist across CF versions (that said, that method's been there for years and years); nor would there be any requirement for third-party CFML engines like Lucee to support them. It's a risky suggestion. Not sure how this is simper than using the inbuilt CFML `excludeHeaderRow`? Or are you not using CFML's spreadsheet functionality to read the spreadsheet?

Comment: @AdamCameron sorry, I meant simpler than serializing+replacing+deserializing. My issue was different from the OP's. In fact I was trying to work around ACF's poor handling of query column names so that my Spreadsheet Library will work with it. Your serializing suggestion was spot on and means I'm no longer dependent on that unsupported method (even though I very much doubt it will be dropped and Lucee already has it).

Answer (score 1):

Thats easy:

Query

Select [FIRST NAME]

in output loop of query

["FIRST NAME"]

Answer (score 0):

Try this - set a variable works for me

`<cfset first_name = #spreadsheetData['first name'][CurrentRow]#>`

Answer (score -1):

You cannot. Best practices: I always replace all spaces with an underline.

Comment: da_didi: I know. But i have no permission to change the spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

Simple.  Just alias the select.  Select [FIRST NAME] as FIRSTNAME from qryObj

Comment: While true for SQL Server, the OP is using a [QoQ](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Query+of+Queries+user+guide) which is very different. QoQ's do not support this kind of escaping for column names.