# How do I export the results of a coldfusion10 query to html?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do I export the results of a coldfusion10 query to html?
The user is currently uploading an excel sheet with dogs and I need to output the results of the pitBullcheck query to a html table to show the rows that have pitbulls in them. Breed is a column in the excel sheet.

```
<cffunction name="validateExcelSheet" access="public" output="yes" returnType="void" 
hint="check dogs">

    <cfspreadsheet
    action="read"
    src="#SESSION.theFile#"
    headerrow= "1"
    excludeHeaderRow = "true"
    query = "allData"
    rows = "1-#lastRow#" />


<cfscript>    
 pitBullcheck = new Query(
        sql ="SELECT * FROM allData where breed like 'Pit' ",
        dbtype = "query",
        allData = allData);
        pitBullresult = pitBullcheck.execute().getResult();
   </cfscript>

</cffunction>
```

Comment: on a side note your query is only looking for the value `Pit` as the breed, so you can use `where breed = 'Pit'`

Comment: In this instance, it may be easier to use `<cfquery>`.

Comment: @JamesMohler do you know what I should if the column has a space in the name? For example I'm trying <td>#pitBullresult.DOG NAME#<td> and that's failing with element DOG NAME is undefined in pitbullresult

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301468/how-to-read-columns-with-spaces-from-coldfusion-queries apparently there's nothing you can about spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>breed</td>
</tr>
<cfoutput query="pitBullresult">
  <tr>
    <td>#pitBullresult.breed#</td>
  </tr>
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Then just add additional `<td>` for each column in your query.

Comment: This worked to ouput a table, but what do I do if the column has a space. for example i'm trying <td>#pitBullresult.DOG NAME#<td> and that's failing with element DOG NAME is undefined in pitbullresult.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301468/how-to-read-columns-with-spaces-from-coldfusion-queries apparently there's nothing you  can do about spaces

Comment: Yes, you can.  `#pitBullResult["column name with spaces"][pitBullResult.currentRow]#`

Comment: In the table: <td>#pitBullResult["Dog Name"]#</td>  gives error: A CFML variable name cannot end with a "." character.

Comment: @ScottStroz Also tried <td>#pitBullResult.["Dog Name"][pitBullResult.currentRow]#</td> and same error as previously stated: A CFML variable name cannot end with a "." character.

Comment: why not rename the column from `Dog Name` to `dogName` or `Dog_Name` ?

Comment: According to your comments, you did not try what I suggested. You stated you tried `pitBullResult["Dog Name"]` and `pitBullResult.["Dog Name"][pitBullResult.currentRow]`. Neitehr of which matches what I suggested - `pitBullResult["column name with spaces"][pitBullResult.currentRow]` Can you dump out the query and attach a screen cap to the post?